# Обучающая задача на сортировку и подсчет уникальных слов в списке Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

На обучающем курсе задана следующая задача:

> Дан текст на языке племени Мумба-Юмба. Выведите все слова, встречающиеся в тексте, разделяя их пробелом. Слова должны быть отсортированы по убыванию их количества появления в тексте, а при одинаковой частоте появления — в алфавитном порядке.
>
> ### Подсказка.
>
> После того, как вы создадите словарь всех слов, вам захочется отсортировать его по частоте встречаемости слова. Желаемого можно добиться, если создать список, элементами которого будут кортежи из двух элементов: частота встречаемости слова и само слово. Например, `[(2, 'hi'), (1, 'what'), (3, 'is')]`. Тогда стандартная сортировка будет сортировать список кортежей, при этом кортежи сравниваются по первому элементу, а если они равны — то по второму. Это почти то, что требуется в задаче, а чтобы сделать то что нужно — вспомните про параметр `key` в сортировке.

В этой задаче нужно сдать только ответ для входного файла. Ссылка на входной файл:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Wvn0nT8MVll6Oj1KvRDWq3Z7ekV4xLg2/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113335581115004287089&rtpof=true&sd=true
Написала код для этой задачи. Вроде все корректно, все работает. Но тестирующая система не принимает ответ. Прошу подсказать, что ей не нравится в моих выходных данных. Может быть, не надо в конце знак перевода строки заменять пробелом? Вот код:

```
fin = open('test1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')
words = fin.read().replace('\n', ' ').split(' ')
words_count = dict()
words_count = dict.fromkeys(set(words), 0)
for w in words:
    words_count[w] += 1
words_sorted = sorted(words_count.items(), key=lambda item: (-item[1], item[0]))
for p in words_sorted:
    print(p[0], end=" ")
fin.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вывести результат так:

```
print(' '.join(p[0] for p in words_sorted))
```

Смысл: возможно, системе не нравится лишний пробел в конце, который у вас получается из-за `end=" "`. В моём варианте пробел есть только **между** словами, но не в конце.

Можно ещё вот так добиться того же эффекта:

```
print(*(p[0] for p in words_sorted))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, CrazyElf. Ваша корректировка вывода данных помогла.

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение*:

```
from collections import defaultdict
 
fin = open('test1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')
text = fin.read().replace('\n', ' ')
 
words = defaultdict(int)
for line in text.splitlines():
    for word in line.strip().split():
        words[word] += 1
        
frequency = defaultdict(list)
for word, freq in words.items():
    frequency[freq].append(word)
    
for freq, words in sorted(frequency.items(), key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True):
    for word in sorted(words):
        print(word, end=' ')
```

*взято с CyberForum

Comment: Ну как, помогло?

Comment: К сожалению, нет. Я поменяла последнюю строку на print(''.join(word), end=' '), так как по условию задачи слова должны выводиться через пробел. Весь остальной код не трогала.  Опять пишет: Ваш код не прошел один или несколько скрытых тестов.
Ваш код должен пройти все тесты, чтобы заработать какие-либо оценки. Пробуйте снова. Сейчас попробую Ваш код в чистом виде. Без своих изменений, хотя вывод и не соотвествует условиям задачи. Попробовала. Не канает. Но Ваш код 100% рабочий. И мой тоже 100% рабочий. Там, видимо, дело в каком-то маленьком нюансе. Спасибо за участие.

Comment: `end` в `join` не поможет. Попробуйте теперь